# Change Icon Color in Alert Dialog Using setState of Different File

Tags: android, flutter, android-alertdialog

The problem I am facing is to change the color of an icon from a different class. Therefore, in my application, I need to trigger File 1's setState from File 2.

I have tried callback function but it is not working. Maybe due to lack of experience and understanding.

[File 1 (full file is shown to provide a better understanding of my problem):](https://pastebin.com/VvJq7ARB)

[File 2 (Full file is shown to provide a better understanding of my problem) :](https://pastebin.com/WAVLfJ2H)

Currently, the icon in the alert dialog will only change its color when the alert dialog is reopened (This just trigger setState File 1 from File 1).

My expected result is when the button in the alert dialog is pressed, icon color change instantly without the need of reopened the alert dialogue.

Hopefully, someone may suggest me what and how to implement to achieve the expectation...

Comment: You could use `RFlutter` Alert library for that. It is easily customizable and easy-to-use. Link: https://github.com/RatelHub/rflutter_alert

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your recommendation. It is a nice package. My current version of alert dialogue is working fine. It is just that the colour of the Icon (icon is in File 2) depends on parameter from File 1. Therefore, i need to setState File 1 from File 2 to get the latest parameter. But i do not know how to achieve it..

Answer (score 0):

The color property defaults to the current IconTheme color, if any. Generally, a material design color will be used, as follows:

```
Icon(
 CustomIcon.MyFlutterApp.light,
 color: Colors.blue.shade400, //any color you want
 size: 100,
),
```

Or you could do like this:

```
child: new IconTheme(
    data: new IconThemeData(
        color: Colors.yellow), 
    child: new Icon(CustomIcon.MyFlutterApp.light),
),
```

BTW, I haven't checked the code but it should work.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the feedback. I am using the first method you are recommending and below is how i achieve it.
Icon(
                CustomIcon.MyFlutterApp.light,
                color: teController=="ON"?Colors.yellow:null,
                size: 100,
              ),

It works perfectly except it failed to change color instantly when the condition change :(

Comment: What you exactly mean by 'when the condition changed'?